# Is there a better way to this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have very easy JavaScript/CoffeSscript knowledge. 
I'm wondering if there's a better way to bind the placing the `active` class only when `tableContentsPane` is opened.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#tableContents').click -> 
    $('#tableContentsPane').toggle();
    $("#tableContents").addClass "active" if $("#tableContentsPane").is(":visible")
    $("#tableContents").removeClass "active" if $("#tableContentsPane").is(":hidden")

  $('#tableContentsPane a').click -> 
    $('#tableContentsPane').toggle();
    $("#tableContents").removeClass "active" if $("#tableContentsPane").is(":hidden")
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `if` to see if the table is open or not you can simply toggle the class

```
$('#tableContents').click(function(){ 
    $('#tableContentsPane').toggle();
    $("#tableContents").toggleClass( "active");

});
```

I believe this will meet all your conditions

API reference  http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/